# translate <img width="68" height="18" src="cid:ii_jfppcl910_162a1546c5df71b3">

Tags: codenameone

Reading An Email in Java Swing App.
I have an HTML string received from email that contained an inline image
I retrieved and stored the image "image.001.jpg"
Now I want to View The E-Mail in an JTextPane with the text and inline image

How do I translate the CID:ii_jfppcl910_162a1546c5df71b3 to the jpg image I have saved?
My Resulting HTML line would be:
<img src="image.001.jpg" alt="some_text" width="300" height="200"/>

Thanks In Advance.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest not translating that and just saving the files from the email to a file system storage directory. Then showing the HTML with the `BrowserComponent`. You can pass a path to `FileSystemStorage` into the browser component and it should "just work".